# Matrix characteristics and its polynomial

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

I have a matrix of size $n \times n$, where diagonal entries are $n-1$ and non-diagonal entries are $2n-2$. I have solved for $2 \times 2$ and $3 \times 3$ matrices, but not getting for $n \times n$ matrix. Now I want to find its characteristic equation and it's polynomial. Please, any suggestions.

For the matrix $n \times n$, where diagonal entries zero and non-diagonal entries are $2n-2$, I have got the value $4(n-1)^2$.

Comment: Welcome to Math SX! You want to solve *what* ?

Comment: Sorry , i am finding polynomial.

Comment: Matrix nxn is given I an trying to find characteristic equation and it's polynomial

Comment: What is a characteristic equation and polynomial? Do you just mean the characteristic polynomial: $\det (A - \lambda I)$?

Comment: Yes sir you got it correct , characteristic polynomial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's try a simpler looking problem:

Consider the matrix $$A = 
\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
                1 & 2 & 1 & 1 \\
                1 & 1 & 2 & 1 \\
                1 & 1 & 1 & 2   \end{pmatrix}.$$

We know that if $\lambda_1, \dots, \lambda_m$ are the eigenvalues of $A$ then its characteristic polynomial looks something like $f(x) = (x - \lambda_1)^{k_1} \cdots (x-\lambda_m)^{k_m}$.

Some suggestions:
1. Find what the eigenvalues are.

2. Find what dimensions that the eigenspaces are (i.e. how many linearly independent eigenvectors you have for a given eigenvalue).
3. Hopefully the eigenspaces give you enough information so you can try to construct the characteristic polynomial from that.

Comment: If n=3 then matrix is 3x3 and diagonal entries are 2 and non diagonal entries are -4 , I am getting eigenvalues as -6,6,6.

Comment: What is the characteristic polynomial in that case?

Comment: That's what I am finding the answer

Comment: I was asking a rhetorical question: Suppose that you know that a $3\times 3$ matrix has eigenvalues $-6, 6, 6$. Then what does this tell you about the characteristic polynomial?

Comment: Both are same sir sorry it is for particular care I want for nxn matrix.

Comment: Thank you got it by your hind. The answer is (x+3n-3)^(n-1) (x - (n-1)(2n-3)). Thanks for supporting all your comments. Please verify what I have I got correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since this may be a homework question, I will work it out for the specific case $n=4$; the general case follows as an exercise. The following solution uses the fact that determinants are not affected by adding one row to another.

The characteristic polynomial is

$$p(x)=\det{\begin{pmatrix}3-x&6&6&6\\6&3-x&6&6\\6&6&3-x&6\\6&6&6&3-x\end{pmatrix}}$$

Subtract the last row from each row:

\begin{align*}p(x)&=\det{\begin{pmatrix}-3-x&0&0&3+x\\0&-3-x&0&3+x\\0&0&-3-x&3+x\\6&6&6&3-x\end{pmatrix}}\\
&=(3+x)^3\det{\begin{pmatrix}-1&0&0&1\\0&-1&0&1\\0&0&-1&1\\6&6&6&3-x\end{pmatrix}}\\
&=(3+x)^3\det{\begin{pmatrix}-1&0&0&1\\0&-1&0&1\\0&0&-1&1\\0&0&0&21-x\end{pmatrix}}\end{align*} In the last determinant, 6 times each row is added to the last row. Hence

$$p(x)=(x+3)^3(x-21)$$

For an $n\times n$ matrix, the polynomial should work out to $(-1)^n(x+n-1)^{n-1}(x-(n-1)(2n-1))$.

Comment: Sir every thing is correct but please go through this ,for n=4 ;                         eig([3 -6 -6 -6 ; -6 3 -6 -6 ; -6 -6 3 -6 ; -6 -6 -6 3])= -15 , 9 , 9 ,9. For your answer p(x)=(x+3)^3(x-21) is not talling to the eigenvalues. Please help me out. How to get the correct answer.

Comment: 21 is an eigenvalue. Its eigenvector is (1,1,1,1).

Comment: Your question states 2n-2 on the off-diagonal, not 2-2n. You can repeat the same type of reasoning for that case.